# Unable to load properties from yaml file using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

Below is my (policies.yml) yaml file in which I want to parse/map to classes through spring.

```
urls:
  - url: url1
    actions:
      - action: acton1
        domains:
          - domain: domain1
      - action: action2
        domains:
          - domain: domain1
  
  - url: url2
    actions:
      - action: acton1
        domains:
          - domain: domain1
      - action: action2
        domains:
          - domain: domain1
```

---

this is my configuration class to load yaml file.

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:policies.yml")
@ConfigurationProperties("urls")
public class SecurityURLConfigs {   
    private List<Url> urls = null;  
}

public class Url{
   private String url;
   private List<Action> actions = null;
}

public class Action {
    private String action;  
    private List<Domain> domains = new ArrayList<Domain>(); 
}

public class Domain {
    private String domain;
}
```

but this configuration isn't loading properties from yaml file. Can anybody guide whats wrong in this code.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote your config file is named `policies.yml`, but in the code you try to load `framepolicies.yml`.

Also you set `urls` property as root, but try to get it inside class. I think you should either try to set `@ConfigurationProperties("")` or move the `urls` block inside another and set `@ConfigurationProperties("another")`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon setting @ConfigurationProperties("") solve the issue, now its parsing all properties.